# Ubuntu can't find fair.c of kernel/sched

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, cfs

I am trying to find fair.c file to look at source code to improve CFS algorithm.
In the internet, many advised to look at kernel/sched folder. However, there was only Makefile file.
I am running ubuntu 16.0.4 on virtual box and kernel version is 4.10.
I tried accessing by going into usr/src/linux-header-37-header/kernel/sched
Any ideas..??
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For view the kernel code, you need **kernel sources**, not a *kernel headers*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks! turns out it was in kernel source files! Another question is.. I cannot find kernel/sched.c file... Has the file been moved to other directory??

Comment: File `kernel/sched.c` existed in older kernels, which had no `kernel/sched` folder. Now all schedule-related code is in this folder.